# how to approximate 90th percentile given a stream of millions of numbers

Tags: java, statistics, heap, priority-queue, percentile

I need to calculate the 90th percentile of a stream of numbers that I am getting every second. It could be up to millions of numbers per second, but the 90th percentile just had to be approximated and not necessarily exact. Is a priority queue/max heap the best way to do this, or something else? If so, how would I end up approximating the value?

Comment: Are you processing those numbers in those per-second batches? And the percentile, does it have to apply to the stream overall, or do you just want the latest estimate?

Comment: what does your input distribution look like?

Comment: Are the elements of the stream independent?

Comment: I am calculating the 90th percentile for each second, and each of these seconds might have up to millions of numbers for which I have to calculate the percentile (but approximately, doesn't have to be exact). The distribution is between 0 and 150 and independent.

Comment: So the *values* are between 0 and 150? Create 150 buckets, and increment the corresponding bucket when an item comes in. When you've received all items, start at the largest bucket and start counting items until you've reached 10% of the total. That will be your 90% point.

Comment: Some of the values can end in 0.5 or something, like 60.5- what happens in that case? How would I define the buckets in Java for example?

Comment: You said you needed an approximation. So use rounded values: coerce them to integer. Or, if the numbers always end in 0.0 or 0.5, then define 300 buckets. If the numbers could be .1, .2, .3, etc., then you could use 1500 buckets. Or, you could save the numbers in an array and run Quickselect: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect. There are many different ways to solve your problem. The bucket idea will use less memory and is probably faster, but Quickselect will give you an exact value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method you select will depend on the nature of your data. If you know, before you start receiving the stream of items, how many items you will receive, you can use a heap-based selection algorithm. For example, if you know that you're going to receive 1,000,000 items and you need to know the 90% percentile, then you know that the 100,000th item marks the 90th percentile. To find it, do the following:

```
create an empty min heap
add the first 100,000 items to the heap
for each remaining item
    if the item is larger than the smallest item on the heap
        remove the smallest item from the heap
        add the new item to the heap
```

When you're done, the heap contains the 100,000 largest items, and the root of the heap is the smallest of those. That's your 90th percentile value.

A faster way that uses more memory is to save all of the incoming items in a list, and run [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) to find the 100,000th largest item.

Both of the above will give you an exact answer.

If you know that your numbers will be within some relatively small range, you can create buckets to store them in. For example, you said that your numbers are in the range 0 through 150. So you need 151 buckets. Your values are not whole numbers, but since you said an approximation is fine, you can round the values before putting them into buckets. So something like this should work:

```
buckets = array of 151 values
for each value
    int_value = round(value)
    buckets[int_value] = buckets[int_value] + 1
```

Now that you have a count of each value figuring out the 90th percentile is a simple matter of counting values from the end of the array (the highest values) until you reach 10%. Something like:

```
target = 100000  // we want the top 10 percent
bucket = 150
total = 0
while (bucket >= 0)
    total += buckets[bucket]
    if (total >= target)
        break
    bucket = bucket - 1
```

At this point, the value of `bucket` is your approximate 90 percentile value.

This method will be faster than the other two, and will use considerably less memory. But it's an approximation rather than an exact value.